# Error on crystal report when exporting to pdf asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working with crystal report export pdf with the below code, but when exporting to pdf the error is coming at line no 9.

> Error: Method not found: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ISCRExportOptions.get_ExportOptionsEx()'.

```
    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("FrontRor_S.rpt"));
    DataSet ds = GetData();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    ExportFormatType formatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    crystalReport.ExportToHttpResponse(formatType, Response, true, "Crystal");
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
                    DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                    PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\\SampleReport.pdf";
                    CrExportOptions = doc.ExportOptions;
                    {
                        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                    }
                    doc.Export();
```

Please try this code after `crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);`
This will definitely works.